# How to weight an input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction

I'm trying to train a simple model using TensorFlow.

I want to get an accurate prediction (98%+) for a new input into the trained model.

There is 500 Input's. 1 stands for a Price (500-200.000), 1 for a Construction-Year (1980-2017) and the 498 remaining are either true or false (0/1). Now the 498 Input's are really important (in fact the other two are almost obsolete). So it's all numeric.

I looked through the TensorFlow documentation and couldn't find any tutorial on how to weigh the different input's. e.g. Price/Year should only make up for "10%" of the Prediction (0.05 each) while the remainders make up for the rest (0.9).

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: what is this predicting?  The input is price, year, +498 other features but what is the desired output?

Comment: @wontonimo The desired output is if the new input "equals" trained data to a certain degree. (Well that's to simplified)

To be more accurate: 

The input has to be sorted in categories. Let's say there are 10 different categories. So it should be predicted in which category the input does fit to which degree. If the input fit's into a category with over 98% it is assigned to it in a mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

Construct a learning algorithm that does not choose all of its own weights, but instead only chooses some of its weights.  Specifically, given 500 features the first feature contributes 5% , the second features contributes 5% and the remaining 498 features contribute 95% to the final prediction.

## Solution

This is very similar to the architecture of a *collection of experts*.  Instead of creating 1 network, you will create 3 networks :

- a network that uses feature 1
- a network that uses feature 2
- a network that uses feature 3 through 500

You would create each of these networks as you would a regular network with independant weight matrices and output hypothesis.

That will end in some tensorflow code like

```
y_out_from_price = tf.nn.softmax( h_out_from_price )
y_out_from_year  = tf.nn.softmax( h_out_from_year  )
y_out_from_rest  = tf.nn.softmax( h_out_from_rest  )
```

Where each of these is your categorization prediction.  Your final prediction is

```
y_out_final = 0.05 * y_out_from_price +
    0.05 * y_out_from_year + 
    0.95 * y_out_from_rest
```

My opinion is that this will underperform just using all the features.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try that out when i'm home. Why exactly would this underperform just using all the features?

Comment: let's say that each **h_out_from_...** is a multi layer neural network with non-linearities so that they can calculate functions like **xor**.  This would allow (for example) feature 7 and feature 11 play off of each other in an **xor** logic.  Since price and year are not in the same network as the rest then **xor** like logic (that includes price or year) cannot be even expressed by this network.